# JOB и временные таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

В общем, есть JOB, который имеет 3 шага выполнения, каждый шаг дергает хранимую процедуру, в которой в процессе работы происходит следующее:

```
if object_id(N'tempdb..#tmp__',N'u') is not null drop table #tmp__

CREATE TABLE #tmp__ (...)

--Какая-то вставка во временную таблицу
--Вешаем PK после вставки
```

Так вот, по непонятным причинам, JOB временами падает на момента, когда вешается PK. Если тут же перезапустить JOB на этом же шаге, то все успешно отрабатывает. Двоится там ничего не может., тогда бы и повторные запуски с такими де параметрами падали с ошибкой.

Есть ли еще причины по которым так может происходить, кроме как дубли в данных? Может эта темповая таблица остаться после предыдущего шага выполнения JOB'a? Тогда странно, почему он не падает на `CREATE TABLE`,

Comment: _"--Вешаем PK после вставки"_ как вы это делаете? Покажите команду.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] JOB временами падает на момент, когда вешается PK. [...]
>   Есть ли еще причины по которым так может происходить, кроме как дубли
>   в данных? [...]

Так может происходить, если PK на временной таблице создаётся командой

```
ALTER TABLE #tmp
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tmp PRIMARY KEY ...
```

Делать так на временных таблицах - плохая практика (по крайней мере в production коде). И вот почему.

Чтобы можно было создавать временные таблицы с одинаковыми именами в разных сессиях (а также в разных контекстах одной сессии), SqlServer уникализирует их имена.

Предположим мы создали временную таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp ([ID] int NOT NULL);
```

Выполнив следом запрос

```
select name
from tempdb.sys.objects
where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tmp');
```

мы можем получить полное (уникальное) имя временной таблицы, это будет что-то наподобие `#tmp__...__00000000C542`.

Добавим теперь к нашей таблице первичный ключ

```
ALTER TABLE #tmp
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tmp PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);
```

и проверим его имя

```
select name
from tempdb.sys.key_constraints
where parent_object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tmp') and type = 'PK';
```

запрос вернёт `PK_tmp`, т.е. имена ограничений на временных таблицах **не уникализируются**.

Первичный ключ (как и другие виды ограничений) является отдельным объектом схемы (хотя и дочерним для таблицы). Иметь два объекта с одинаковым именем в одной схеме не разрешается. Из этого вытекает следующее.

Если в то время, пока существует наша таблица `#tmp`, кто-то в параллельной сессии создаст какую-то временную таблицу и захочет добавить к ней свой `PK_tmp`, то создать таблицу ему удастся, а ключ - нет.

Верно и обратное. Если кто-то подсоединился к серверу, создал временную таблицу и добавил к ней свой `PK_tmp`, то наш код, выполненный в неподходящий момент, упадёт. Вы и сами могли обрушить свой код, отлаживая его в отдельном окне.

Т.е. на временных таблицах командой

```
ALTER TABLE #tmp
    ADD CONSTRAINT ...
```

ключи лучше не создавать.

Если ключ всё-таки нужен, то нужно использовать один из вариантов синтаксиса с автоматическим формированием имени ключа.

При создании временной таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp ([ID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE #tmp ([ID] int NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ([ID]));
```

либо при изменении

```
ALTER TABLE #tmp
    ADD PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);
```

так SqlServer сам назначит ключу уникальное имя (наподобие `PK__#tmp______3214EC2788A01C40`).

Также, вместо ключа можно использовать уникальный индекс (индекс не является самостоятельным объектом схемы, поэтому может быть множество индексов с одинаковыми именами на разных таблицах).

Comment: Хм... Ну там ошибка не то, что он существует, а то что якобы какие-то дубли в PK. Такое впечатление, что он вешается на какую-то не ту темповую таблицу. Надо было мне конкретизировать ошибку... Однако, ваша информация так же полезная.